# Python (3.6) doesn't let me draw on IDLE

Tags: python

I am new to Python as I just started recently. I managed to draw on Python using `Turtle` just to have a play around. However, since I installed some modules, I yet again learned how to draw and I did the same thing as I did before but only when I run the module it comes up with an error. The only thing I have changed is that I installed some modules so it might be that.

This is what is says when I run it;

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/Ed/Documents/Drawing.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import turtle
>   File "/Users/Ed/Documents/turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
>     tut = turtle.Pen()
> AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'
> ```

I don't know what it means. And please let me know if you have the answer or have gone through the same experience as me and have solved it.
Also if I went wrong please let me know.

Comment: If you created a file called `turtle.py`, rename it.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are running is called just like the module, so Python is probably trying to import the method from your file, where you did not define any `Pen` class. Rename the file and that should fix it.

On a general basis, never call files that contain `__init__.py` files in the same directory as modules you want to import. It will cause confusions to the interpreter

Comment: I am sorry, what file is this you speak of?

Comment: There is no code, I am telling you to change the file name. It is not so complicated to understand

Comment: I did that and nothing happened.

Comment: The file you are running man! You are running a file cakes turtle.py, rename it.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it did solve your problem @EdPoole